# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: jenkins, curl, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am using docker image of jenkins and deployed it on a kubernetes cluster. 
I have written a groovy script to run a curl command on a dynamically created slave on jenkins and have also configured slave to run curl commands,but getting the above mentioned error in my jenkins console. I have also checked whether curl is installed on my slave node using `where curl`, it gives response as `/usr/bin/curl`.

I have tried to run only the curl command on my slave node, it works. But when I call the groovy script file using Jenkins it gives the error `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": error=2, No such file or directory`.

Comment: This happens because Jenkins uses non-login shell and your $PATH is not the same when you run curl from bash.

Comment: Do you mean to login to Jenkins as a user to use the login shell or something??Because there is no option in the jenkins to login as I am using its Docker image.

Comment: No, there is non such option. The way I solved it is to make sure that curl is on the sh path. .bash_profile and .bashrc are not loaded when you run slaves from jenkins. I think it was /etc/environment for my distro.

Comment: @georgeok This time I even made sure that curl is in my path by setting the path of the curl in the `PATH` variable by creating a new slave docker image using ENV. When I do `echo $PATH` it shows the path of the curl as `/usr/bin/curl`. Then to I am facing the same error in the jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess groovy can not find curl, try calling curl with the full path as in:

```
def process = ['/usr/bin/curl', 'https://someurl'].execute()
process.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
process.waitFor()
```

as an alternative, if you just need to do a http get request to some url, you can do this in plain groovy without the dependency on curl by:

```
def response = 'https://someurl'.toURL().text
```

< edit after comments >

You could also do a post request using pure groovy and something like the following (untested):

```
def url  = 'http://api.duckduckgo.com'.toURL()
def body = 'some data'
url.openConnection().with {
  doOutput      = true
  requestMethod = 'POST'

  // send post body 
  outputStream.withWriter { writer ->
    writer << body
  }

  // set header 
  setRequestProperty "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

  // print response
  println content.text
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion using `/usr/bin/curl` . Now am getting this error `Cannot run program "/usr/bin/curl": error=2, No such file or directory`. And about the alternative u suggested, I am required to pass headers and also perform a POST request using curl

Comment: You can do headers, but you can not do post requests using the alternative method. Looks to me like curl is not available in the context you are running this script in.